# Does the Catholic word Priest actually mean "Presbyter?" Or is it a conflation of roles?

Tags: catholicism, protestantism, terminology, priesthood, elders

The problem as I understand it is a combining of roles.. not confounding or mixing  but fusing the roles into something different. The role of the priest doesn't seem to match the role of the Presbyter. But if they are the same, then why the difference.

Comment: cf. [this answer](https://history.stackexchange.com/a/46355/3202)

Answer (score 3):

## Priest (*sacerdos*)

[*Sacerdos*](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059%3Aentry%3Dsacerdos1) literally means "a giver of the sacred". St. Jerome, in his [*Vulgate*](http://vulsearch.sourceforge.net/) Latin translation, uses *sacerdos* to translate [ἱερεύς](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0057%3Aentry%3Di(ereu%2Fs), for example in [Hebrews 7:17](http://drbo.org/x/d?b=drl&bk=65&ch=7&l=17-#x):

> μαρτυρεί γαρ ότι συ **ιερεύς** εις τον αιώνα κατά την τάξιν Μελχισεδέκ
>
> *Contestatur enim : Quoniam tu es **sacerdos** in æternum, secundum ordinem Melchisedech.*
>
> For he testifieth: Thou art a **priest** for ever according to the order of Melchisedech.

## Presbyter (*senior*)

The [*OED* says this regarding "presbyter"](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/150608):

> The Vulgate regularly renders Greek [*πρεσβύτερος*](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0057%3Aentry%3Dpre%2Fsbus) ["old man"], *πρεσβύτεροι*  by Latin *senior* [from [*senex*](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059%3Aentry%3Dsenex)], (plural) *seniores* ["ancients"], except in [Acts 20:17](http://drbo.org/x/d?b=drl&bk=51&ch=20&l=17-#x), [22:5](http://drbo.org/x/d?b=drl&bk=51&ch=22&l=5-#x), where it has *majores natu* ["ancients"], and in [Acts 14:22](http://drbo.org/x/d?b=drl&bk=51&ch=14&l=22-#x), [15:2](http://drbo.org/x/d?b=drl&bk=51&ch=15&l=2-#x), [1 Timothy 5:17](http://drbo.org/x/d?b=drl&bk=61&ch=5&l=17-#x), [19](http://drbo.org/x/d?b=drl&bk=61&ch=5&l=19-#x), [Titus 1:5](http://drbo.org/x/d?b=drl&bk=63&ch=1&l=5-#x), [James 5:14](http://drbo.org/x/d?b=drl&bk=66&ch=5&l=14-#x), where the Greek form is retained as *presbyter*, *presbyteri* ["priests"]. The same men who in [Acts 15:2](http://drbo.org/x/d?b=drl&bk=51&ch=15&l=2-#x) are called *apostoli et presbyteri* ["apostles and priests"], are called in verses [4](http://drbo.org/x/d?b=drl&bk=51&ch=15&l=4-#x), [6](http://drbo.org/x/d?b=drl&bk=51&ch=15&l=6-#x), [22](http://drbo.org/x/d?b=drl&bk=51&ch=15&l=22-#x), [23](http://drbo.org/x/d?b=drl&bk=51&ch=15&l=23-#x) *apostoli et seniores* ["apostles and ancients"]; the Greek having uniformly *ἀπόστολοι και πρεσβύτεροι*.

Comment: The roles seem different between the two, even though they may share the same etymology. It seems to be a combination of the Jewish Priest and the Christian Elder. Hierous and πρεσβύτεροι respectively. So was the change merely caused by common practice... or is it a conflation of roles?

Comment: @VernonChoin What "seems to be a combination of the Jewish Priest and the Christian Elder"? Also, Catholic priests even today are "according to the order of Melchisedech".

Comment: Also note that in Catholicism not all sacerdos are presbyters (i.e. Bishops are "priests" in the sense of sacerdos, but not priests as "elders")

Answer (score 2):

It is both a conflation of words and of roles.

> This word [translated as PRIEST] (etymologically "elder", from presbyteros, presbyter) has taken the meaning of "sacerdos", from which no substantive has been formed in various modern languages (English, French, German). The priest is the minister of Divine worship, and especially of the highest act of worship, sacrifice. 
>   [New Advent](http://www.newadvent.org/cathen/12406a.htm)

So admitadly, there was a diverging from what had taken place.  That diverging accompanied the role of a sacerdotal priest in the Catholic Church.  Originally, the ELDER (πρεσβύτερος presbyteros) was in a leadership role for each location of the Body of Christ.  It had nothing to do with a separate role of some who believer they offer a same repeating sacrifice day after day.

> (3) in the Christian churches, those who, being raised up and qualified by the work of the Holy Spirit, were appointed to have the spiritual care of, and to exercise oversight over, the churches. To these the term "bishops," episkopoi, or "overseers," is applied (see Acts 20, ver. 17 with ver. 28, and Tts 1:5, 7), the latter term indicating the nature of their work, presbuteroi their maturity of spirtual experience. The Divine arrangement seen throughout the NT was for a plurality of these to be appointed in each church, Act 14:23; 20:17; Phl 1:1; 1Ti 5:17; Tts 1:5. The duty of "elders" is described by the verb episkopeo. They were appointed according as they had given evidence of fulfilling the Divine qualifications, Tts 1:6-9; cp. 1Ti 3:1-7; 1Pe 5:2;
>   [Vines Expository Dictionary of New Testament Words](https://www.blueletterbible.org/lang/lexicon/lexicon.cfm?Strongs=G4245&t=KJV)

For the Body of Christ, all believers are priests who offer spiritual sacrifices.  Ironically, it is Peter who tells us this.

> Ye also, as lively stones, are built up a spiritual house, an holy priesthood, to offer up spiritual sacrifices, acceptable to God by Jesus Christ.
>   1 Peter 2:5

So, the Catholic word translated as PRIEST came from PRESBYTER that orginally (and still to some) meant ELDER whose role was to study, teach, lead.  At that time, all believers were of the same priesthood as Christ who is our High Priest.  Once the word PRESBYTER became unhinged from its New Testament context, the newly redefined PRESBYTER role became one of a like Old Testament PRIEST who was of continually physical sacrificing.

Comment: Kindly if you are answering questions tagged "catholicism" and asking about a "catholic word" please stick to Catholic understandings and not inject your own Protestant interpretations of Church history.

Comment: check the quotes from the Catholic dictionary and scripture.  thanks.  there is also a tag protestantism.  so kindly be sure of what you are asking.

Comment: The question explicitly says "Catholic word" if OP were asking for just what the word "priest" meant, why would they use that term? Furthermore, the question cannot be answered apart from a denomination since it strikes at one of the key distinctions between Catholicism and Protestantism. Lastly, I have checked the sources you refer to and they do not unambiguously claim what you do. It's silly to think that a Catholic encyclopedia supports a Protestant interpretation of the word priest, which is what you imply but the source does not.

Comment: The Catholic word "has taken", which is to say that it wasn't originally.  I understand it is hard to accept what the Catholic dictionary says when it doesn't support the current idea of a sacerdotal priest in the Catholic religion.

Comment: The Catholic encyclopedia does say "has taken" true but that doesn't mean it supports the Protestant idea that presbyter became "unhinged" from its New Testament context. That's called reading into a source something that isn't there. I'm not claiming that presbyter originally meant "priest" (in the modern English sense) only that to say it became unhinged as though the concepts were conflated is at best a Protestant theory of Church history and not uniformly supported by a reading of early Church texts.

Comment: It's far more logical that as a deeper understanding of theology occurred a term already in use would take on a more specific Christian meaning. e.g. demon in Christianity refers to a fallen angel, but the Greek word originally was more generic. Ekklesia is the root of the word translated as Church in languages like Latin, Spanish, Italian etc yet in Greek originally it wasn't specifically a religious assembly, let alone Christian.

Comment: The problem, since you agree the word priest "has taken" on the meaning of sacrificing, is for you to explain for example the Hebrew Christ's sacrifice done once for all time and sat down or Peter's claim believers are all priests offering spiritual sacrifices, etc.  My answer addresses the OP.  I can't help the dictionary's admittance of the obvious.

Comment: It is not for me to explain what other questions surely touch on. Your answer does not address in so far as it excludes the Catholic version of theology when it asks specifically for one (At least that's a reasonable inference from the use of "catholic word" in the question title).

Answer (score 1):

The words in the text of scripture have different meanings. Whether tradition has 'conflated' them would be a matter of linguistics research, and thus would be outside the scope of this website.

πρεσβύτης, *presbutes*, [Strong 4246](https://biblehub.com/greek/4246.htm) meaning 'old man' occurs three times in the NT (see Young's Analytical Concordance) and πρεσβῦτις, *presbutis*, [Strong 4247](https://biblehub.com/greek/4247.htm) meaning 'aged woman', occurs once.

Then πρεσβύτερος, *presbuteros*, [Strong 4245](https://biblehub.com/greek/4245.htm), meaning an elder, a member of the Sanhedrin, an elder of a Christian assembly (see Thayer on the link), occurs 66 or 67 times.

And πρεσβυτέριον, presbuterion, [Strong 4244](https://biblehub.com/greek/4244.htm) occurs three times, meaning 'elders' 'estate of elders' or 'presbytery' [KJV translation].

It is clear that in the gospel accounts, *presbuteros* are not priests as they are described as being in the company of priests. Priests and *presbuteros* are two different categories of persons documented in mixed companies who came to Jesus in their respective official positions representing the Jews.

It is also clear that when applied to elders in the Church, they do not carry out any priestly functions, only functions relating to the gospel and to church discipline.

The entire epistle to the Hebrews proves beyond a peradventure that the priesthood was a temporary installation in Israel which portended the coming of the only real Priest, the Messiah, Christ Jesus.

With his coming, all other priesthoods passed away, never to be re-instated.

A careful examination of the information above, linking to Strong and Thayer, proves the point beyond dispute.

Comment: Since the question asks about "the Catholic word", simply quoting Scripture concordance seems insufficient

Comment: @eques   The word 'priest' is not a 'Catholic' word. It is an English word. The word is defined by dictionary definition and by lexical usage : not by any other organisation.

Comment: The question refers it to as such and as such it would be quite reasonable to understand it in the context of "what does the word mean according to Catholicism"

Comment: @eques As they say in the House of Commons : _I refer the honourable member to the comment I just made above_  >>> ^ We do not get to make up language. Language is what it is.

Comment: In the same vein, I kindly ask the honorable member to not miss the point. Repeating the same point does not advance the conversation. It's not a question of who makes up language (it being a moot point whether your claim is sustainable) but it absolutely is clear that terms do have definitions contingent upon context. Your claim is roughly similar to saying it would be correct to answer "Does the Catholic word Mass mean a sacrifice?" with "No" because some Anglicans both refer to their services as Mass and yet don't acknowledge it as sacrifice.

Comment: @eques The 'context' of priesthood is Christ himself. The word 'priest' has no meaning other than He. Because he would come, priests were ordained in Israel. But only until he came. _This_ is the context. From the Beginning. The word 'priest' in Hebrew means something. And when it is translated into Greek (or English) it retains that meaning. And no authority on earth has the right to alter such meaning.

Comment: Now you are moving the goal posts. There is no word "priest" in Hebrew nor in Greek. They have their own words which are rendered by analogs in English; therein lies the question. The fact that we are even having the discussion is predicated upon the fact that someone somewhere did associate presbyter with sacrificial since the English word "priest" derives from presbyter not from hierus or sacerdos. And you can bet that person did not have your Protestant theology in mind when he did so.

Comment: @eques Priest in Hebrew is _kohen_. High Priest is _hak kohen_. Priest in Greek is _hierreus_. High Priest is _archiereus_. Priest in English is _Priest_. High Priest is _High Priest_. I am going to stop commenting now. No further comment.

Comment: Priest is only Priest in English because Presbyter became used for a offerer of sacrifice. To conclude presbyter means elder to the exclusion of priestly doesn't address the question which does assume some awareness of the Catholic idea. You at best conclude scripture uses it one way, haphazardly suggest the development of term is off-topic and waves it away.

Comment: @eques I refer you to my previous comment . . . . which was - no further comment.